# vertical white space based on text

Tags: spacing, pdftex

I am using the code below to create a question with its solution. If I set `ans` command (which I created) to true the solution will print, and if I set `ans` to false the solution will not print.

My concern is that when I set `ans` to false I need to have a vertical white space. What I would like is to have the vertical white space occupy the same vertical space as the solution would, i.e., when I am using `\null\vspace{4cm}`, I would like this number (that I have set manually) to be based on the actual size of the solution text.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{datetime}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Print Answers
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newboolean{ans}
\newcommand{\sol}{true} % set this to false if you don't solution to be printed 
\newcommand{\Ans}{{\color{blue}\textbf{Ans:}} }
\newcommand{\Sol}{{\color{blue}\textbf{\vskip0.001inSolution:\vskip0.05in}}}
\newcommand{\solspace}{\Sol \newpage}

\newtheorem{exm}{Example}[section]
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set the Margins, Header and Footer 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[lastpage,user]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,fancyhdr}

\VerbatimFootnotes % Required, otherwise verbatim does not work in footnotes!

%\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}  % Add line after header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0in}    % no line added before footer
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\textheight = 700pt  % length of body text 
%\textwidth  = 500pt
\marginparwidth = 2in
\headsep    = 0.2in
\voffset    = -0.4in
\headheight = 15pt

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\fancyplain{}{Mr.Stat}} % Course number on the left on 2nd page
\chead{\fancyplain{}{\emph{MLR}}}  % Course name in the center on 2nd page
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{Class2}}           % date of the course on 2nd page
\fancyfoot[L]{{\color{red}\copyright~~\the\year}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small\hspace{5pt}{\color{red}\emph{Page \thepage\ of \zpageref{LastPage}}}}

\thispagestyle{plain}  % If this is enable the header will not appear

%===========================================================================================
% Start document 
%============================================================================================

\begin{document}
\noindent 
%======================================================================================================================
\section{Introduction}
Assuming that $E(e_i)= 0,$ the response function for regression model is:
\[
E(Y_i) = \beta_0+\beta_1X_{i1}+\cdots+\beta_kX_{ik}
\]
This response function is a hyperplane, which is a plane in more than two dimensions. It is no longer possible to picture this response surface.

%------------------- Example 7.1 ----------------------
\begin{exm}
    Back to the example 1 find the 90\% CI for the mean response at $X_h= \begin{pmatrix}1\\6.5\\0.35\end{pmatrix}$
%****************************** Solution ********************************
\setboolean{ans}{\sol}   
\ifthenelse{\boolean{ans}}{\Sol
The fitted value at $X_h$ is 

\[
Y_h = X'_h\beta = \begin{pmatrix}1,&6.5,&0.35\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0.6666667\\1.3166667\\-8.0000000\end{pmatrix}= 0.667 + 1.317(6.5) -8(0.35) = 6.425
\]
and
$$
SSE =Y'Y - \beta'X'Y = 396.57- 395.225 =1.345 \mbox{ then } MSE= 0.1494.
$$
The 90\% CI for $E(Y_h)$ is 
\[
\begin{array}{lcl}
    E(Y_h)&\in& \left(6.425 \pm 1.812\sqrt{(0.1494)(0.18125)}\right)= (6.425 \pm 0.117)= (6.308371, 6.541629)
\end{array}
\]
}
{
\Sol
\null\vspace{4cm}
}

\end{exm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\vphantom{your text}`? Please do not change the page parameters by hand, use `\usepackage{geometry}` for this

Comment: Possibly `\color{white}` from package `xcolor` would do it? The color command is used within a group, and affects everything in the group. If you are printing to paper, that should do it. But if the PDF is viewed by computer, the invisible white text can still be selected, because it is there.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you please more specific please and give an example

Comment: Perhaps the `censor` package might help.  There’s one thing I don’t understand, anyway: what do you want to happen if the omitted solution would span more than one page?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti What I want to make sure the space I leave for the solution is consistent with what is needed. I mean I don't want to keep space 3 cm when I only need 1 cm, that can be find out only from the answer text right?